# When does crafting unlock?

Tags: kittens-game

I've bought 11 workshops, but the crafting sub-tab hasn't unlocked below the upgrades tab. I have more than enough wood to craft beams(about 2k), but nothing has shown up.

Is there an upgrade or building I'm missing? I checked the wiki, which just says it unlocks with the workshop.

Answer (score 2):

Found it, Construction needed to be unlocked on the Science tab.